# Storing function pointer from constructor to private variable

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, function-pointers

I'm attempting to develop an embedded library for microcontrollers in a (potentially futile) attempt at being device-generic. Essentially, I have a `struct` declared in the header, called `CallbackStruct`, that has a whole bunch of function pointers for downstream control of a UART object (i.e. the `Serial` object of Arduinos, just to point out one potential usage).

The issue is that I'm not quite sure how to assign one function pointer (especially when dereferenced from a struct) to another that is stored as a private variable. Essentially, I need an understanding of the proper C++ syntax for function pointers. Here's what I have so far:

The header:

```
class SomeUARTDevice {
public:
    struct CallbackStruct {
        void    (*init) (int);
        void    (*xmit) (char *);
        int     (*recv) (void);
        int     (*avbl) (void);
        void    (*flsh) (void);
        void    (*kill) (void);
    };

    SomeUARTDevice (struct CallbackStruct *sc);

private:
    void    (*init_callback)    (int);
    void    (*xmit_callback)    (char *);
    int     (*recv_callback)    (void);
    int     (*avbl_callback)    (void);
    void    (*flsh_callback)    (void);
    void    (*kill_callback)    (void);
}
```

And, then in the class source:

```
SomeUARTDevice::SomeUARTDevice (struct CallbackStruct *sc) {
    init_callback = sc->init;
}
```

Is this the proper way to assign the function pointer (and if not, how far am I off - by a little bit, or by a mile)?

Note that if there happen to be other syntactical boo-boos, I quickly threw this together as an example to demonstrate the issue without the clutter of the main work-in-progress.

Comment: Is there a reason why you would not want to store a copy of the struct?

Comment: do you realise that what you're trying to do is manually re-implement virtual functions?

Comment: @OnMyLittleDuck The struct is mainly so I wouldn't be required to jam all the function pointer references into the constructor argument space. I suppose I could call off the struct directly, but at the time of writing I hadn't worked through that permutation.

Comment: @RichardHodges Had I a better command of virtual functions in C++, I'd probably be able to answer that better. That being said, I'm trying to develop a means for the class I'm building to be mapped onto the existing execution environment, not trying to envision class derivation.

Comment: Before this turns quickly into an after-the-fact discussion of "What I Don't Know About C++", I used funcptrs for two reasons - the first being that I want to practice with them more, and the second being that I interchange between C and C++ frequently, so I'd like to practice ways of doing things that are interoperable between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks fine. Function pointers work pretty much just like any other pointer.

But note that you could initialize your members directly, using the constructor's initializer list:

```
SomeUARTDevice::SomeUARTDevice(const CallbackStruct *sc)
    : init_callback(sc->init)
    , xmit_callback(sc->xmit)
    // etc
{}
```